# Android WebView Image zoom

Tags: webview

I am working with WebView right now. I use it, because I want to zoom some images in my app. My image get's zoomed in and out, as it should. The only problem is that it does not work correctly. When I completely zoom out I can see only, like 1/9 of whole image. I wanted to use `getDefaultZoom()` and set x and y as WebViews height and width, but the method is deprecated. How can I fix the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, getDefaultZoom() wouldn't fix the issue. Next thing - deprecated doesn't mean that you can't use it. It means that there is a better method to do that or that it will be soon removed from features. It's highly unlikely that using deprecated functions will mess up your app. Using `getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN)`; should fix  your issue.